# Eaton Powerware 9170+ (with ConnectUPS Web/SNMP Card) - Cannot make all SNMP queries nor change SNMP community name

Tags: configuration, snmp, ups

Does anybody has this UPS (Eaton Powerware 9170+)? I'm having some problems with it.  Unfortunatelly all related to this product is bad documented.  My problems:

1. Don't know where to change SNMP community name in it.  The old administrator did that, but I can't figure out where to make that change. I tried both telnet and web interfaces, with no luck.
2. There is a problem with SNMP:

2.a) First, not all possible OIDs are returned on a `snmpwalk`. This is strange, because `XUPS.MIB` file has more OIDs than the one that the UPS returns. For instance, I can't retrieve `1.3.6.1.4.1.534.1.7.3` that is `xupsOnBattery`.

2.b) Even without an input source (which means that we are out of external energy), it don't change its inputVoltage values.

Has anybody got this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to configure your UPS through Telnet and configure "Set Write Access Managers".